# *** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/httpd double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: apache

I have CentOS-6.6,httpd-2.2.15,php-5.4.40 installed.I am getting error in httpd error log.

*** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/httpd: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f0a6d7d4320 ***

Here is the full error log http://pastebin.com/5vTVVdYg

I have reinstalled httpd and php,but no luck.
Can anyone explain why it's showing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: I have this problem too

Comment: I have this problem too